# Visual Studio C++ - Library throwing an exception when included in a different project type

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, static-libraries

I have two projects, let's call them A and B. A builds to .dll and B builds to .exe. Both of them use my static library. They link to an exact same .lib file. A works fine. B, however, crashes with "Access violation writing location" at first point where the library tries to dereference some heap allocated memory.

What can be the cause of this? Why would a dll run fine and exe not?

Thanks for an help